# PHP: Assign include data to a variable?

Tags: php, include, strip-tags

This is logically what I want to achieve:

```
$variable = include "file.html"; 
strip_tags($variable);
```

1. Is it possible
2. If not, how can I run the strip_tags function on the contents of a file that I want to include. I just want to get the text contents of the file, not the html data.

Hope I make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are willing to do is possible using `file_get_contents` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead of `include`.

Example:

```
<?php
$file = 'file.html';
$data_without_html_tags = strip_tags(file_get_contents($file));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this very easily by buffering the cache:

```
ob_start();
include("whatever.html");
$whateverHtml = ob_get_clean();
```

More on output control [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).